# What is the difference between .SFUIText and .SFUIDisplay?

Tags: ios

Can someone help. I would like to find out the difference between these two choices that iOS offers?

Comment: The Human Interface Guidelines discuss this: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/

Comment: And see videos: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10175/